# Notice: Undefined Variable - form processing?

Tags: php

I created a sample form and code below to illustrate. I know i can turn notices off in php but would rather fix the problem rather than ignore it.

When i create forms i do like what i have posted below, obviously this is just a sample with no sanitization etc.

I sort of know why i get the **Notice: Undefined Variable** which i know sounds dumb but not sure what's the easiest and correct way to solve it.

Could one of you great people out there show me how to stop this notice appearing?

It's only now i realised i did not have all error reporting on in WAMP and i have created allot of forms and i really don't want to be doing loads of re-editing code to fix it, hence i'm looking for a good, simple solution to solve it so i can go into all my forms and sort it once and for all.

```
<?php
// check if form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // fetch form data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // check form fields
    if(empty($name)){
        $error .= 'Enter name <br />';
    }
    if(empty($username)){
        $error .= 'Enter username <br />';
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $error .= 'Enter email <br />';
    }

    // check if errors exist
    if(isset($error)){
        echo $error;    
    } else {
        // process form as normal   
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($name)) echo $name; ?>" />

<label for="name">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($username)) echo $username; ?>" />

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

Comment: The notice should also say *which* variable and which line.

Comment: Hi well it only says it's the first error depends on what fields i enter. I think it's because i user $error .= (notice the . dot) and im concantinating something to a variable that does not yet exist. I think thats the problem. but doing $error = ' '; to set the $error variable sets it so it won't process doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the problem is the first string concatenation `$error .= "something"`, because `$error` does not exist before.

**Easy fix:** Initialise `$error` with an empty string and use `!empty($error)` instead of `isset($empty)`.

Comment: Thanks Felix :) I will just need to re-arrange code a little. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PHPLOVER: You're welcome :) If your code is like above, there is not that much to change. Just add `$error = '';` and change the `if` clause. Also remember to always sanitize user input. **Never** trust user input.

Comment: Hi Felix, it ok i have plenty of regex functions and sanitize functions in my library for sanitization the code i posted above was just a sample to show people what i meant. Thanks

Comment: @PHPLOVER: Good :) Just saying, because it is somehow obligatory to mention it ;)

Comment: yeah... i missed that line about not wanting to re-edit lots of forms. this is easy enough. also, good on ya for preventing this error/warning. i once got on a project with tens of thousands of lines of code that never went through a profiler. it spent 5-8% of it's time in the error handler because of stuff like this and not having quote marks on array indexes eg `$array[apple]` instead of `$array['apple']`.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments changokun. It has taken me a minute or two to fix them all :) . Sadly it seems most just advise to turn off php notices. By turning it on i also spotted some redundant code to nothing major but it was worth doing, it was code i thought i removed before lol.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could simplify things:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $error = "";

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        $error .= 'Enter name <br />';
    }

    echo $error;
}
```

repeat that isset() section for each var.

Comment: `$_POST['name']` will always be set (if `$_POST['submit']` is set). It could have an empty string though. So you would have to change `isset` to `!empty()`.

Comment: that's true, but don't forget `$_POST['iAmAcheckboxField']` wouldn't nec. be set. so really you want `if(isset(X) and !empty(x)...` I was expecting phplover to expand on everything.

Comment: You are right, checkbox fields are not set if the are not selected.